# Valgrinds says I have a huge leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm very new to C++ and I'm struggling with my code, It's longer than what I'm posting but I isolated the leak down to these lines -

Node class -

```
class Node
{
 public:
  int name;
  Node *topedge;
  Node *bottomedge;
  Node *leftedge;
  Node *rightedge;
};
```

Main ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <node.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
     Node* grid [10][10];


  //populate grid                                                                                                                                                                                              

  int h= 0;

 for( int i= 0; i < 10; i++ ){

    for( int j= 0; j < 10; j++ ){

      grid[i][j] = new Node(); //this is where it says the leak is

      grid[i][j]->name = h;

      h++;

     }

  }


  return 1;

}
```

The errors :

```
==12581== 4,000 (40 direct, 3,960 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==12581==    at 0x4C300EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12581==    by 0x4009D8: main (main.cpp:17)
```

Later in my code, I fill the references for each node in the node class and then I only leak 40 bytes in 1 Block, But I'm not sure how to go about these leaks.

Comment: Well, I can't spot a single `delete` in your code, while you do a bunch of `new` allocations. Could that be the problem?

Comment: True what has been said, when you got a pointer as data member of your class, you have to add a custom destructor, in which you-ll write a `delete` (or `delete[]` if an array) statement for each pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet, as presented here, creates a new `Node` for every element in the 2D array but never `delete`s it - it's only freed when the process terminates. Valgrind identifies this as a memory leak, as this memory is never "properly" cleared.